# .Net Mvc RazorView & Entity Framework: Controller not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Razorview and Entity Framework and I am trying to achieve the following: I have a dropdown(id=ColumnName) that has a list of column names and a textbox(id=SearchValue) for value to be searched from a table. On click of a button, I am trying to retrieve from the database, the record where the column name is 'ColumnName' selected and value='SearchValue'. I am getting a **404 Resource Not found error** on click of the button. I am not sure where I am going wrong. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<select id='mySelector' name="ColumnName">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value='Country'>Country</option>
    <option value='Title'>Title</option>
    <option value='State'>State</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="cs" name="SearchValue">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("FilterByColumn", "CountryController")?SearchValue=' + document.getElementById('cs').value + '&ColumnName=' +document.getElementById('mySelector').value" />
<table id='myTable'>
// values
</table>
```

CountryController:

```
public ActionResult FilterByColumn(String ColumnName, String SearchValue)
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchValue))
    {
        List<Country> result = new List<Country>();
        result = db.Countries.ToList();
        result = db.Countries.Where(ColumnName + ".Contains" + "(\"" + SearchValue.ToLower() + "\")").ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Note: I have other methods like create,edit in this controller. 
Also the URL rendered which throws the 404 error is :
/CountryController/FilterByColumn?SearchValue=sample&ColumnName=Title

Comment: Unless your have a controller named `CountryControllerController` (which I doubt), its `@Url.Action("FilterByColumn", "Country")`

Comment: My controller is called CountryController.cs and the url rendered seems to be correct : /CountryController/FilterByColumn

Comment: No its not!! Your url needs to be `/Country/FilterByColumn` (read the previous comment)

Comment: I apologize if this is redundant but I am new to this. I did try what you said but I am now getting this error: The view 'FilterByColumn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. It seems to be searching for the 'FilterByColumn' method as a view.

Comment: That is because you do not have a view named `FilterByColumn.cshtml`. If you want to return a specific view (which dos not match the name of the method), then its `return View("yourViewName", result);`

Comment: Oh yes. Got it thank you very much. It works now !

Comment: An additional question: How would I keep the search value in the text box when the page is loaded after button click. Now it gets cleared on button click.

Comment: You need to ask a new question (comments are not for asking questions). But you need to start using view models and bind to your model properties using the `HtmlHelper` methods, not generating manual html (and you would be far better off updating your view using ajax anyway rather than making redirects.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as flollows

```
   <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("FilterByColumn", "CountryController")?SearchValue=' + document.getElementById('cs').value + '&ColumnName=' +document.getElementById('mySelector').value" />
```

Never give CountryController, just Give Country and try. Edit your code as follows and try

```
  <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("FilterByColumn", "Country")?SearchValue=' + document.getElementById('cs').value + '&ColumnName=' +document.getElementById('mySelector').value" />
```

and give the parameters in same order in both razor and controller

Answer (score 0):

your button code as follows

```
input type="button" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("FilterByColumn", "CountryController")?SearchValue=' + document.getElementById('cs').value + '&ColumnName=' +document.getElementById('mySelector').value" />
```

but in the controller you have written as follows

```
public ActionResult FilterByColumn(String ColumnName, String SearchValue)
```

but the order of parameters are different. So change your controller as follows.

```
public ActionResult FilterByColumn(String SearchValue,String ColumnName)
```

Hope this will work out.

Comment: The order of parameters makes no difference